# Remove additional zeroes from varchar

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I want to remove all zeros `0` from the beginning of a string:

SQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('00008800000006',0,7)  AS serno ,
       SUBSTR('00008800000006',8,14) AS lot
FROM dual ;
```

Expected result:

- SUBSTR('00008800000006',0,7)  = '0000880' => Serno = '880'
- SUBSTR('00008800000006',8,14) = '0000006' => lot   = '6'

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are using Oracle, you may try with this:

```
select
 REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR('00008800000006',0,7), '^0+(.*$)', '\1') as Serno,
 REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR('00008800000006',8,14), '^0+(.*$)', '\1') as lot
 from dual;
```

**OUPUT**

```
SERNO    LOT

880      6
```

You may also use LTRIM

```
select
 ltrim(SUBSTR('00008800000006',0,7), '0') as Serno,
 ltrim(SUBSTR('00008800000006',8,14), '0') as lot
  from dual
```

**OUPUT**

```
SERNO    LOT

880      6
```